# analytic solution of a definite integral

Tags: integration, probability-theory, definite-integrals

Integrate the following
$$\int_0^\infty \alpha\,\beta\, c\, k\, x^s\, x^{c-1}
(1+x^c)^{k-1}
\left[(1+x^c)^k-1\right]^{-\beta-1}
\left[1+\gamma \left((1+x^c)^k-1\right)^{-\beta}\right]^{-(\alpha/\gamma)-1} \,dx$$

where $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma$, $c$ and $k$ are positive real numbers and $s$ is positive integer.

This is how I have tried to solve it enter image description here

substituting [image] and putting beta and gamma equal to "1" and taking its derivative we have [image]

expanding the first term using binomial expansion we have [image]
=[image]

substituting t-1=1/y we getenter image description here again substituting 1+y=1/v , we get [image]

the terms in the integral form beta function therefore

[image]

[image] is the solution I come up with. Can anyone hint another solution?

Note: When I put beta and gamma not equal to one I need to expand the term with "s" power twice using binomial expansion.

Comment: If the asterisk is the usual product, it can be omitted... Was the formula copy-pasted from a math program?

Comment: Under *no* circumstance use asterisks for multiplication (except in computer programming, where you don't have any other choice, of course). In mathematics, it most commonly denotes *convolution*, which is another type of beast entirely. If you need a multiplication sign, use `\cdot` ($\cdot$) instead.

Comment: Surely, this cries out for subsituting $u=(1+x^c)^k-1$, does it not?

Comment: Or even $u=((1+x^c)^k-1)^{-\beta}$. But I guess troubles come from the factor $x^s$.

Comment: What does it mean by open bounty?

Comment: @Kyson if you answer it and the OP likes it, they will award you the 50pts beyond any upvotes and accepted answer.

Comment: Where did this integral come from ?

Comment: @Sary this is the s-th momoent of a probability distribution

Comment: When $\alpha/\gamma$ is an integer, the integrand is a rational fraction that should be manageable by residues. All poles can be found analytically I guess. In the non-integer case, the last factor generates a nasty branch point.

Answer (score -1):

This is how I have tried to solve it
[image]

substituting [image] and putting beta and gamma equal to "1" 
and taking its derivative we have
[image]

expanding the first term using binomial expansion we have
[image]
=[image]

substituting t-1=1/y we get[image]
again substituting 
1+y=1/v , we get 
[image]

the terms in the integral form beta function therefore

[image] is the solution I come up with. 
Can anyone hint another solution?

Note: When I put beta and gamma not equal to one I need to expand the term with "s" power twice using binomial expansion.

Comment: You should post this in the body of the question.

Comment: You shouldn't have this in both your question and answer.  Plus you have yet to give your bounty, so why have you already selected this as your answer?

Comment: @Squirtle since it seemed highly unlikely that anyone was giving a solution I accepted the answer that I posted.

Comment: It's still not a good reason; if anything, this only prevented an answer from coming....why bother with a question if the question is already answered? This only hurts you.

Comment: Plus, this is not an answer since it soon assumes that beta = gamma = 1 although the question does not.